# Run factor in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, cpu, parallelism

how to run Linux's `factor` in parallel, i.e. utilize all CPU cores?

I have tried to run `factor <prime number>` but unfortunately only one CPU core is being utilized.

Comment: factor runs superfast, I don't see the issue here... can you give an example ? `time factor 8780830139614786527864584691780192830 > real 0m0.004s`

Comment: what exactly do you want, I do not think factor command would affect the usage of CPU core ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't! To use multiple cores/processors a program has to be written to do so, and `factor` isn't, but it can't handle numbers large enough that it should make a difference anyway:

```
> LANG=C factor 23324334789983497346867676887877338391988484874
factor: '23324334789983497346867676887877338391988484874' is too large
```

(that number is just the result of randomly hitting the numeric keypad, the first factor is quite obvious)

Comment: Ok, then implementing multi-core support within `factor` is not necessary (except then at the same expand support for large enough numbers, which is not going to happen for `factor` since it's supposed to be a simple tool for simple (small) numbers). Which tool for large primes with multi core support would you suggest?

Comment: 2*3*44836651474393175401*86701147472711188085570879

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27759/whats-the-best-way-to-factor-a-256-bit-number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stress test your CPU usage, there is nice tool here called [Stress](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/), as an alternative, given what Henrik said in his answer, that it isn't possible using the `factor` command.